# Oracle PL/SQL: How to pretty print a large number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with type `NUMBER(38)` and when I print numbers in PL/SQL they show similar to:

```
MY_ID
----------
1.9351E+14
1.9351E+14
1.9351E+14
```

What can I do to print these as the full number?

Comment: Hint:  `to_char()`.

Comment: Formatting in the front-end or reporting application has the advantage that numbers will still be aligned to the right. `to_char()` converts them to strings, and they will be aligned to the left.

Answer (score 3):

You need `set numwidth 30`

```
SQL> select 1024000*1024000*1024000 from dual;

1024000*1024000*1024000
-----------------------
             1.0737E+18

SQL> show numwidth
numwidth 10
SQL> set numwidth 30
SQL> select 1024000*1024000*1024000 from dual;

       1024000*1024000*1024000
------------------------------
           1073741824000000000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends. What do you mean by "print"? Also, what is the application through which you interact with the database?

The best place to format the output from your queries is your front-end or reporting application. The illustration below, all done in SQL*Plus, shows how to format a numeric column so that numbers are "printed" in natural format, instead of scientific notation. Note that the COLUMN command is a SQL*Plus command which has absolutely nothing to do with SQL (in particular, with SQL functions such as `to_char()`).

```
SQL> select 1.9351E+14 as num from dual;

       NUM
----------
1.9351E+14

SQL> column num format 999999999999999

SQL> select 1.9351E+14 as num from dual;

             NUM
----------------
 193510000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp) link which provides extensive details on number formatting.

You can use the to_char function as below to pretty print (with 1000s separator)

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR( MY_ID, '999,999,999') from MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Try that answer with the OP's sample data (which he has provided) and you will find just one of the possible problems with this solution.